# Limiting NetCat listening to specific network

Tags: netcat

I would like to get your help to figure out how to use NetCat to listen to a specific port accepting connection only from the hosts in a specific network.
I have a server that I would like to share a file with a group of clients only using NetCat (or any other tool).

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than changing the title of your question to say "RESOLVED," please just accept the correct answer. That is the correct way to indicate that a resolution has been found.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do using the netcat version from RedHat using the command line below:

*nc -l --allow "IPs" -p "port number"*

Example:

```
nc -l --allow 192.168.0.10,192.168.0.15 -p 8080
```

Any other different IP that tries to connect will be refused.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed netcat-openbsd instead of netcat-traditional (these specific names are from Debian), then you can listen to a specific address:

```
nc -l 192.168.5.6 9999
```

But this doesn't validate the source address to prevent other networks from accessing it. It just limits which local address, which is good for limiting the interface, but not the source address.

To limit the source address, you will need to use something more, like iptables. Or rules in web server config (like apache, nginx, lighttpd).

Or a python program. Here's a simple python example I wrote for someone a while back, modified to check client address and send the file (without any caching):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# Just a skeleton tcp server that accepts infinite connections and ignores all data

import socketserver

listen_address = "localhost"
port = 9999

def log(message):
    print("%s" % (message))

class ListenerHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    # For handling input
    def handle(self):
        print("handling client %s" % (str(self.client_address)))

        if self.client_address[0] == "127.0.0.1":
            print("ok")

            with open("somefile", "rb") as f:
                while True:
                    data = f.read(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    self.request.send(data)

        else:
            print("rejected")


class ListenerServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

def run_server():
    socketserver.ThreadingMixIn.allow_reuse_address = True
    socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True

    server = None
    try:
        server = ListenerServer((listen_address, port), ListenerHandler)
        log("Starting server... hit ctrl+c to exit")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        log("Stopping server...")
        server.shutdown()
        exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```